# How many stack frames does insertion sort consume?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, insertion-sort

How many stack frames does insertion sort consume, if the list to be sorted is n elements and stored entirely on the heap?

#### Complexity

O(n^2) or O(nlogn)?

What's the difference when it is stored entirely on the heap?

Comment: Insertion sort is iterative, so it runs from the current stack frame. It can be implementd in a non-recursive setting. It shouldn't make any difference if the array is static, local (stack), or allocated (heap).